# Is there any vanishing criterion for elements of a tensor product of algebras?

Tags: field-theory, tensor-products

Let $k \subset L$ be a field extension, $\mathrm{char}(k) = p$. I have some polynomial $f(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in k^{1/p}[X_i], f^p \in k[X_i]$, with at least one coefficient not in $k$, such that $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$, $x_i \in L$. (Of course, both can be embedded in $\overline{L}$.)

I want to prove that its image (i.e. by $aX^{(I)} \mapsto a \otimes x^{(I)}$) in $k^{1/p} \otimes_k L$ is nonzero.

This is not the same thing as

[Testing whether an element of a tensor product of modules is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288431/)

since there is no helpful linear basis; I'm not even sure if this is the way to approach it. I would appreciate any helpful comments.