# When do we have $m\otimes n = 0$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules ($R$ a commutative ring with identity). Let $m \in M$ and $n \in N$. Is there any necessary and sufficient condition to have $m\otimes n = 0$ (as an equation in $M\otimes_RN)$.

Comment: For example when $ann(n)+ann(m)=R$.

Comment: @user52045 your condition is only sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is such a criterion (Bourbaki, Algèbre commutative, ch. I, §2, no. 11, lemma 10). See also the duplicate question [math.SE/288431](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288431).

There is also a "trivial" but still useful criterion: For every bilinear map $\beta : M \times N \to T$ we have $\beta(m,n)=0$.

Comment: Merry Xmas Martin. May I ask you a small question in number theory? It is not that big I post it in site? I want just a hint or good direction and don't want to make you any troubles. May I ask it here? :-)

Comment: Elsewhere. Press "Ask a question".