# $2\otimes 1$ is non-zero in $2\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I had the following doubt:

> Show that the element $2\otimes 1$ is $0$ in $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ but not a zero in $2\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

I was able to prove $2\otimes 1$ is $0$ in $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ by shifting $2$ using tensor property .
now I can't see how to prove it's non-zero in $2\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

kindly help out.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288431

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clearly $2\otimes 1$ generates $2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}$. So it is enough to prove that $2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is nonzero. But what would it mean if it was zero? This would mean: any $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map from $2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $P$ is zero. But, for example, the map $(2z,x)\mapsto zx \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is nontrivial.

$\textbf{Edit}$: This is essentially the same approach John suggested, noting that for any ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$ the isomorphism $A \otimes_A M \cong M$ is given by sending $a \otimes m$ to $am$.

Comment: please can you help explaining why is the map $(2z,x)\mapsto zx \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ non-trivial .

Comment: Take $z=1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x=1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, their product is $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

There's a homomorphism from $2\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ defined by $2s \otimes q \mapsto s \otimes q$. So now: can you prove that

$$
1 \otimes 1
$$
is nonzero in the latter group?

Comment: How to prove $1\otimes 1 $ is not zero?

Comment: I deliberately left that for the asker (and others) to do, because I think it's a valuable exercise. That may make my answer a bad answer, but I'm willing to take that risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it helps me. Especially that exercise

Comment: My pleaseure. Now let's both delete these comments. :)

Comment: Done !..........